# IE/Mozilla Resizing Issue

Tags: html, css, image

I'm consistently having troubles with the lack of resizing properties with IE and Mozilla. To beat this issue the easy way, I put some inline CSS styling into my images to set the width to what I would like. However today I checked out my site after my programmer did some updates and something went wrong..... Can anyone help me on how to fix these image issues FOR GOOD?

View http://www.fishingreports.com in Chrome then IE/Mozilla

....even the logo in the footer has

```
<img src="/media/images/logo_gray.png" width="180px" alt="fishing reports">
```

as code, but the image still won't obey.....

Comment: Post the relevant code here or in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You don't use 'px' inside the width attribute of an element (it's not CSS) - [you just say `width="180"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp). Then again, you should probably be doing that using CSS, not attributes, where you _would_ be saying `width: 180px`.

Comment: It should be noted that browsers are known to completely ignore `width="180px"` as it has an invalid property value. It's not the issue at hand though, just another semi-related issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [CSS validator output for your site](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fishingreports.com%2Fcss%2Fweb.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en), and most specifically the error on line 368:

> Parse Error ;' text-align: center; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em 0;
>   border: solid #2b4130; border-width: 1px 0; text-align: center;}
>   .single article h2, .single article h3 { font-family:
>   Headline,'Helvetica Bold','Arial Black',sans-serif; font-size: 2em;
>   color: #2b4130; margin: 0.5em 0;}

Looking up the relevant line it says:

```
.single article blockquote { font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;' text-align: center; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em 0; border: solid #2b4130; border-width: 1px 0; text-align: center;}
```

There's a stray apostrophe after `bold;`, causing the **entire rest of the file** to be treated as a string by Firefox and IE. The rules constraining the size of the `img` elements and the footer rules are below it, and as such being ignored. Chrome manages to do some garbage checking apparently to be able to resume parsing on the next line.

Fix the apostrophe and you'll see your styles getting applied correctly again.

As a sidenote - the number of `!important` declarations in your CSS is ridiculous, and makes predictable cross-browser rendering a total mess. You should consider stripping ***all*** `!important` instances out of there and only re-adding the ones that are actually *needed*. Always keep in mind that `!important` is a last-resort fix for issues that have no better solution using [normal rule specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: Thanks Niels! Yeah...I'm the culprit of the !important things - I'm a bit of a CSS noob. I'll definitely be spending some time with that CSS validator and cleaning things up. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Added an extra note on how to resolve the `!important` overuse as well.